# SQL left join on a table with alternative results - implementing selection order for optimal performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I would like to join two rather large tables in an optimized way and looking for a solution here.

One table has Customers (with ID as primary key).

This to be left joined with:

Address table has different types of address data - it also has ID as pk, Customer ID as a foreign key but with duplications, type of address for the given row and the address itself.

I would like to implement a **selection order** - if the most preferred address type (in this case Postal) exists for a customer, then take the this address type else take second preference (in this case Delivery) as the next best and then the third type (Locational) as least preferable. There might be more than 3 options in the real problem, maybe 5-6.

To illustrate my problem:

Customer table:

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | some data Joe |
| 2 | Eva | some data Eva |
| 3 | David | some data David |
| 4 | Adam | some data Adam |

Address Table

| id | cust_id | address type | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Postal | Postal type address for Joe |
| 2 | 1 | Delivery | Delivery type address for Joe |
| 3 | 1 | Locational | Locational type address for Joe |
| 4 | 2 | Delivery | Delivery type address for Eva |
| 5 | 2 | Locational | Locational type address for Eva |
| 6 | 3 | Locational | Locational type address for David |

The desired output would look like this:

| id | name | data | address type | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | some data Joe | Postal | Posta type address for Joe |
| 2 | Eva | some data Eva | Delivery | Delivery type address for Eva |
| 3 | David | some data David | Locational | Locational type address for David |
| 4 | Adam | some data Adam | *null* | *null* |

So for customer 1 (Joe) the Postal type address was selected as it did exists. Then for customer 2 (Eva) type Delivery was selected as the second best option, and finally for customer 3 (David) it was the Locational type address. No address was selected for Adam.

I could figure out some options with a number of steps, eg. joining address table multiple times and then selecting the addresses with CASE WHEN type wrapping query but there must be an easier way to do this.

Here is a fiddle (MS SQL Server)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e0ffce

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually using, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: I am using SQL Server on this problem

Comment: The query will be different even in MySQL 8 - database products offer only basic ANSI SQL compliance. All have significant custom features and quirks. MySQL is one of the worst offenders and MySQL 5.7 specifically had too many quirks and lacked too many features. One of those is `ROW_NUMBER()` and CTEs, that can be used to calculate a rank for each row inside a partition, for a specific order. This was added in MySQL 8

Comment: I made a mistake in defining the question - actually the address types are not sortable, I just have given A, B, C as an example, but actually are like Postal Address, Delivery Address, Primar Address etc. The given solution only works if address types are in fact in alphabetical order.  Rephrasing the question... Sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CTE` with `DENSE_RANK()` on your `Address` table. To pick up Customers that do not have an address, add a `COALESCE` to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY
             CASE WHEN address_type = 'Postal' THEN 1 
                  WHEN address_type = 'Delivery' THEN 2 
                  WHEN address_type = 'Locational' THEN 3 
             ELSE NULL END ASC) AS dr
  FROM Address)
SELECT a.*, b.address_type, b.address
FROM Customer a
LEFT JOIN CTE b 
ON a.id = b.cust_id
WHERE COALESCE(dr, 1) = 1
```

**Result:**

| id | name | some_data | address_type | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | some data Joe | Postal | Postal type address for Joe |
| 2 | Eva | some data Eva | Delivery | Delivery type address for Eva |
| 3 | David | some data David | Locational | Locational type address for David |
| 4 | Adam | some data Adam | null | null |

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HHJ86E_c) here.**

Comment: This will also work in MySQL 8 but *not* MySQL 5.7. MySQL will complain about `rank` but changing the alias works

Comment: Well, its tagged `sql-server`, so MySQL is irrelevant here. I know there was some confusion with the description prior to an edit made on it so I understand why you're mentioning this. Good point though, for fun I've changed the reserved word `rank` in the alias.

Comment: I made a mistake in defining the question - actually the address types are not sortable, I just have given A, B, C as an example, but actually are like Postal Address, Delivery Address, Primar Address etc. Your solution only works if address types are in fact in alphabetical order.

Comment: @GaramvölgyiMihály No worries. I changed the `ORDER BY` to use the `id` column to account for this change and added a `COALESCE` to the `WHERE` clause to pick up Customers that don't have an Address table record for the ranking. Change it to `WHERE dr = 1` if you want to exclude Customers that don't have an Address record.

Comment: IDs are again not sortable. Just a random ID. Can you look at the modification I posted? Take the credit for it, your answer was very helpful, and maybe you can suggest some improvements as this is definitely not the best.

Comment: Sure, I see what you need now with the address_type. I wasn't aware of the sorting, I'll try to modify it. Do you need Adam's record to appear (with the null value)?

Comment: @GaramvölgyiMihály I've added your `CASE` statement directly in the `ORDER BY` for the ranking. This should minimize the complexity a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CTE` with `DENSE_RANK()` on my Address table with an explicit order using `CASE WHEN` does the trick.

Slight modification of GRIV's answer above:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_ID ORDER BY addr_order ASC) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN Address_Type LIKE 'Postal' THEN 1 ELSE
         CASE WHEN Address_Type LIKE 'Delivery' THEN 2 ELSE
           CASE WHEN Address_Type LIKE 'Locational' THEN 3 ELSE null 
           END
         END
       END AS addr_order
    FROM Address
 ) z )
SELECT a.*
  , b.address_type
  , b.address
FROM Customer a
LEFT JOIN CTE b 
  ON a.id = b.cust_id
  AND rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number()over(partition by Cust_id order by [address type] asc) as Rn. Now use a cte or subquery to get the Rn=1 which will get you the desired result. I hope it works for you .